# htaccess redirect when there is a space in url

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, redirect, web

I want to redirect from a old url which still appears in the google search to the new one. the old url is this:

```
http://www.marionettecolla.org/file%20_mostra_milano/mostra_marionette-milano.htm
```

and I want to redirect it to the home page:

```
http://www.marionettecolla.org/
```

I used this in my .htaccess:

```
Redirect http://marionettecolla.org/file\ _mostra_milano/mostra_marionette-milano.htm http://marionettecolla.org/
```

but I am getting Error 500... Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't just escape space like that **"\ "**. The proper way to do it is **"\s"**.

Although I am not sure if putting "\s" in place of space in htaccess file would do the trick. Please let me know if it worked.

Comment: `\s` is too broad. it matches any whitespace, not just space.

Answer (score 22):

this should works:

```
Redirect 301 "http://marionettecolla.org/file _mostra_milano/mostra_marionette-milano.htm" http://marionettecolla.org/
```

just put it between pair of double-quotes `" ... "`

**Update:**

This is another way also, should works for any kind of spaces:

```
redirectMatch 301 http://marionettecolla.org/file[\s]_mostra_milano/mostra_marionette-milano.htm http://marionettecolla.org/
```

Comment: Mahsa, check this out, I've added `301` just right next to the `Redirect` ... it should works now

Comment: I've updated the solution ... you can see that `[\s]` there. This one is also should works ...

Comment: if you use double quotes, then all of the other characters that normally required escaping via regex become invalid. This is a solution with huge side effects, only suitable for narrow cases, like this one.

Comment: don't use 301 redirects, they are cached on the client browser and you lose control, effectively making it permanent.

Answer (score 3):

Try this it works even we tested:

redirect 301 "/file _mostra_milano/mostra_marionette-milano.htm" http://marionettecolla.orgx/" http://marionettecolla.org

### Posted by

alapati

Comment: don't use 301 redirects, they are cached on the client browser and you lose control, effectively making it permanent.

Answer (score -1):

redirectMatch 301 ^/careers[\s]/(.*)$ http://www.soheil.com/careers/$1