# Redirect urls with spaces via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, space

I want to redirect the following url :
/wp-content/uploads/images/TOWER/Dark%20Tower%20Official%20Art.html

I tried the following in the htaccess file :
RedirectMatch "/wp-content/uploads/images/TOWER/Dark\ Tower \ Official \ Art.html" url [L,R=301]

But it doesnt work as it gives me a 500 error.
Any idea of how I could fix this?

Thanks !

Comment: Your syntax seems wrong (first argument would be 301)  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch .You don't need the `\\` as the string is already quoted. cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670703/htaccess-redirect-when-there-is-a-space-in-url

Comment: Indeed, I mixed up several things. 

The following seems to work for individual urls :
RedirectMatch 301 "/folder/folder2/stuff stuff2" url

Is there a way to redirect with 1 rule, all that contains : "/stuff stuff2/  ?

Comment: That's kind of a different question but check out `Redirect`: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Answer (score 0):

Change every %20 to \s (RegEx whitespace character)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp\-content\/uploads\/images\/tower\/dark\stower\sofficial\sart\.html$ /new-link [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: It does seem to work for individual urls, thanks !  

Any idea of why the following rule do not seem to work for a groupe of urls?  

RewriteRule ^wp\-content\/uploads\/images\/tower\/tower\simages\/$ /wp-content/uploads/images/TOWER/Tower_Images/$1 [L,R=301]  

I want to redirect all urls containing :  
/wp-content/uploads/images/TOWER/Tower Images/***stuff  

to :  
/wp-content/uploads/images/TOWER/Tower_Images/***stuff

Comment: Ok, am sorry that my reply is hardly readable. I did add two spaces at the end to add line breaks, but it doesnt work...

Comment: $1 is the first captured group. Check this redirect: RewriteRule ^wp-content\/uploads\/images\/TOWER\/Tower\sImages\/(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/images/TOWER/Tower_Images/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: Very late reply, but thanks a lot @JarekBaran : it doest work and now i understand !